# Can't execute a MySQL request in my PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, function

Hi I can execute my code in my main page but I want to make an include page with all of my function. When I execute this code in the main page that work. But when I try to execute a MySQL request in a function it doesn't work...

```
include('databaseConnexion.php'); 

function showFirstname($idUser)
{

    $users = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '" . $idUser . "'");
    while ($user_info = $users->fetch())
    { 
      echo $user_info['firstname']; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you including databaseConnexion.php on pages that do not work?

Comment: Are you using PDO or MySQLi? Show "databaseConnexion.php" too.

Comment: Are you including the main page in other pages too?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a good problem statement.

Comment: How do you declare the `$bdd`? we must see the included file code.

Comment: Hi, this is my databaseConnexion.php <?php
try
{
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=thenafsk_night;charset=utf8', 'thenafeesk_d', 'sagdg3434t2g3!');
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>